# Kafka High Level Consumer Fetch All Messages From Topic Using Java API (Equivalent to --from-beginning)

Tags: apache-kafka, java, consumer

I am testing the Kafka High Level Consumer using the ConsumerGroupExample code from the Kafka site.  I would like to retrieve all the existing messages on the topic called "test" that I have in the Kafka server config.  Looking at other blogs, auto.offset.reset should be set to "smallest" to be able to get all messages:

```
private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId)    {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", a_zookeeper);
    props.put("group.id", a_groupId);
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
    props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "10000");     

    return new ConsumerConfig(props);
}
```

The question I really have is this: what is the equivalent Java api call for the High Level Consumer that is the equivalent of:

bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning

Answer (score 7):

Basically, everytime a new consumer tries to consume a topic, it'll read messages from the beginning. If you're especially just consuming from the beginning each time for testing purposes, everytime you initialise your consumer with a new groupID, it'll read the messages from the beginning. Here's how I did it :

```
properties.put("group.id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

and read messages from the beginning each time!

Comment: Thanks! Needed it for test purposes. I suppose this is because you can reuse the same data for different purposes?

Comment: @user1758777 Yes, I had needed each of the different tests to work on the same data.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need to use the "low level SimpleConsumer API"

> For most applications, the high level consumer Api is good enough.
>   Some applications want features not exposed to the high level consumer
>   yet (e.g., set initial offset when restarting the consumer). They can
>   instead use our low level SimpleConsumer Api. The logic will be a bit
>   more complicated and you can follow the example in [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example).

This example worked for getting all messages from a topic with the following arguments: (note that the port is the Kafka port, not the ZooKeeper port, topics set up from [this example](http://kafka.apache.org/08/quickstart.html)):

```
10 my-replicated-topic 0 localhost 9092
```

Specifically, there is a method to get readOffset which takes kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime():

```
long readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer,a_topic, a_partition, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime(), clientName);
```

---

Here is another post may provide some alternate ideas on how to sort this out: [How to get data from old offset point in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935755/how-to-get-data-from-old-offset-point-in-kafka)

Comment: What you used to achieve it? to read all the messages from topic.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch messages from the beginning, you can do this:

```
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils;
ZkUtils.maybeDeletePath("zkhost:zkport", "/consumers/group.id");
```

then just follow the routine work...

Answer (score 0):

```
 Properties props = new Properties(); 
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
 props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
 props.put("group.id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

This properties will help you.