# Reset topic offset by creating a new consumer group at every application restart

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Kafka topic and a consumer with a consumer group assigned (a must) in a Spring Cloud application. As a requirement, in every application restart I need to start reading all received messages from the beginning. This was supposed to be achieved by the `resetOffsets` property, but it is clear from [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/67) that it currently doesn't work.

I found [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561147/how-to-read-data-using-kafka-consumer-api-from-beginning) used in kafka consumer api, that suggest assigning a new random name to the consumer group in every restart as a way to start reading from the earliest. Is it possible/recommended in Spring Cloud Stream? How could I define a dynamic name to a consumer group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would work with SCSt too but, as you say, it's a bit tricky to set a random group id, although you could set it as a `System.property` before launching the `SpringApplication`.

If you were using spring-kafka directly, it's easy, just implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and you can `seekToBeginning` when the partitions are assigned.

However, with SCSt, you don't have direct access to the listener.

One workaround would be to manually do the seek before you launch the `SpringApplication` by creating a consumer with the same group id. It gets a bit tricky, though if you have multiple instances of your app because your might get different partitions each time.

We'll look again at fixing that issue (I just made a comment on it).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options if you require the application to restart from the beginning everytime:

1. You can reset the committed offset to `earliest` before restarting the application using the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool (`kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.scala`)
2. Upon restarting, the application can seek to the beginning and manually commit offset 0. If you have `auto.offset.reset` set to `earliest` even if 0 is not a valid offset, it will restart from the beginning.
3. You can use a different consumer `group.id` value every time. In your Consumer `Configuration` bean, insert in the `Properties` object something like:

   ```
   properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
   ```

Finally, do you use the committee offset at all ? If not, just disable `enable.auto.commit` then the application will always follow the `auto.offset.reset` setting.

Options 1 and 2 are usually preferred as they keep a consistent `group.id` allowing to easily add consumer instances to the group and monitor th group.

Answer (score 0):

in **spring-kafka,** if you're configuring consumer vía configuration files such as  *application.yaml* (instead of programmatically) you can get this with **SpEL** (spring expressing language) to provide an **UUID-based consumer group** on each execution **+ earliest offset**

```
# consume-all-configuration
auto-offset-reset: earliest
group: consumer-local-#{ T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString() }
```