# Is it correct to use Java Kafka Consumer without commit operation?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to read set of records from start offset to end offset. I use for this purpose dedicated Kafka consumer. I am OK with at least once semantic (in case, if given application instance goes down, and new applications instance re-reads records from that start offset).

So, can I use such code?

```
private static KafkaConsumer<Long, String> createConsumer() {

    final Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

    return new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
}

public void process() {

    KafkaConsumer consumer = createConsumer();
    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("topic", 2);
    consumer.assign(List.of(topicPartition));

    long startOffset = 42;
    long endOffset = 100;

    consumer.seek(topicPartition, startOffset);

    boolean isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
        final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);

        for (ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record : consumerRecords) {
            if (record.offset() >= endOffset) {
                isRunning = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    consumer.close();
}
```

So:

- I have no `commit()`
- I disable `auto-commit`
- I have no `group-id`

Is it correct code? Or it has some hidden problems?

Comment: You can, even though it looks like you have wrong technology. What would be wrong with loading those events into a proper DB and reload it on demand? This answer could be [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561147/how-to-read-data-using-kafka-consumer-api-from-beginning) as well. There are couple of ways to achieve what you want to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data using Kafka Consumer API from beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561147/how-to-read-data-using-kafka-consumer-api-from-beginning)

Comment: You should also change your code  
 to use `props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");`

Comment: @senseiwu is `props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");` more fast?

Comment: if you don'T add it, then you won't consume from the earliest offset for a new consumer.

Comment: @senseiwu I cannot understand, why you talk about `earliest` offset? My initial task about reading from some `start` to some `finish`. It is not about `earliest` offset.

Comment: ok, I overlooked that. Then you could. What would be in any case wrong with committing already consumed messages?

Comment: @senseiwu as I understand, `commit` is network request to `kafka broker`. So, it is additional load on kafka broker and networking, right? It seems, that I can reduce these actions.

Comment: Offset commits are done using a binary protocol over TCP. They are relatively lightweight

Comment: @senseiwu can you tell me, why I have 500 ms duration of synchronous commit execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct usage, and you shouldn't run into any issues.  It's not *typical* usage of a Kafka consumer, but it is allowed.

From the official `KafkaConsumer` javadoc (my highlights):

https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

> **Controlling The Consumer's Position**
>
> In most use cases the consumer will simply consume records from beginning to end, periodically committing its position (either automatically or manually). ***However Kafka allows the consumer to manually control its position, moving forward or backwards in a partition at will.*** This means a consumer can re-consume older records, or skip to the most recent records without actually consuming the intermediate records.
>   There are several instances where manually controlling the consumer's position can be useful.
>
> ...
>
> ***Kafka allows specifying the position using seek(TopicPartition, long) to specify the new position***. Special methods for seeking to the earliest and latest offset the server maintains are also available ( seekToBeginning(Collection) and seekToEnd(Collection) respectively).